# Function return value always equal to one no mater what SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row evaluates to

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA function that always returns 1 regardless of the actual last cell value. When I break into the code I see that SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row evaluates properly to the row with the last piece of data (say row 31) yet crystalBall still returns 1. How does the value of 31 get converted to 1 when I call this function in my spread sheet?

```
Function crystalBall() As Integer
crystalBall = Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
End Function
```

If I convert this to a sub and run it as a macro the same piece of code runs just fine.

```
Sub crystalBall()
MsgBox(Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
End Sub
```

UPDATE: Trying some of the recommendations and adding further clarifications;

On Sheet1 I pass the date from A3 to crystalBall() in B3 as [=crystalBall(A3)]. Eventually I will do something with this date. But I can't get past the first part which is...I want crystalBall() to return the row containing the last date in the sheet "TEST". It should return 31, but returns 1.

```
Public Function crystalBall(d As Date)
crystalBall = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TEST").Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
End Function
```

For now I am going to use this code below to find the last date row in TEST since it actually returns 31 like it is supposed to.

```
Function crystalBall(d As Date)
crystalBall = Worksheets("TEST").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Images of code editor and worksheets linked:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qsp6.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUbEo.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD9Os.png

Comment: A couple of checklist thoughts on creating User Defined Functions.  First, put the word 'Public' before the word function to make it accessible outside the module.  Second, do not use the same name for your module as for your function- don't name your module crystalBall.

Comment: The value of 31 doesn't get converted to 1. You haven't qualified the worksheet (specified the workbook) so the results will depend on the location of the codes and possibly on which workbook is active (`ActiveWorkbook`). Please share the locations (workbooks, modules) of the procedures (they can't be in the same module) so we can accurately answer your question. If e.g. your intention was to apply this to the first worksheet of the workbook containing this code, you should use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)...`.